# How to fix "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil

Tags: json, swift, xcode, decoding

tried a couple things but still can't seem to fix this

My app makes an api call from SeatGeek grabbing a list of events. I have a Model file, Request file, and my view controller file, i will link those.

I grab the json just fine, but decoding it is where i get problems.

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef9HY.png)

[API Request file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caouz.png)

[View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzA9r.png)

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQzLB.png)

[some of what my JSON looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu1FR.png)

Comment: Please post text, not images. The error clearly states that the value for key `performers` in `events` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json returns an array of `performers` not an object, so it should be

```
var performers = [PerformersInfo]
```

Comment: cool, I am glad it helps! Please, next time you asked a question here, add your code not the images. It is quite time consuming check your code this way. Thanks!